# UpdateCursor 'is not defined' Python

Tags: arcpy, table, update

I have several files (shapefiles). Table 1 has only one row with several fields whereas Table 2 has several rows.
What I want is to take a value from Table 1 and populate all rows in Table 2. I used a SearchCursor to find the value I want and an UpdateCursor to populate the rows.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Ecodis_clip_split" 
#set workspace to folder with values

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor ("Table1.shp", "", "", "area_ha", "") 
#search for the value in attributetable

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Split_wetlandt" 
#set workspace to folder with files which need to be updated

rows = UpdateCursor ("Table2.shp", "", "", "area_eco", "") 
#Update all rows of file with value from SearchCursor above
```

Running this, I keep getting this Errormessage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<module1>", line 17, in <module>
NameError: name 'UpdateCursor' is not defined
```

If something is not defined, this means that Python sees it as a variable? 
Even if I could get rid of the errormessage: would it populate all the rows in Table 2 with the value or do I need to do something else?
Note that I just started to learn Python and never scripted anything what so ever...

Edit 6/17/14 11:32 am

@ Aaron, would this replace the values in Table 2 with my searched values from table 1?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Ecodis_clip_split" 
#set workspace to folder with values

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor (table 1", "", "", "area_ha", "") 
#search for the value in attributetable

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Split_wetlandt" 
#set workspace to folder with files which need to be updated

with arcpy.UpdateCursor (Table 2 ["area_eco"]) 
#Update all rows of file with value from SearchCursor above
for row in cursor:
    area_eco.replace(SearchCursor)
```

EDIT 6/27614 12:04pm

I updated my script to this.
Somehow it deleted my whole attributetable in Table 2 but I got it restored. I run it again and now nothing happens. It does not update the rows, the value in the rows stays 0.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Ecodis_clip_split" 
#set workspace to folder with values

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor ("Table1", "", "", "area_ha", "") 
#search for the value in attributetable

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Wetland" 
#set workspace to folder with files which need to be updated

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor ("Table2", "", "", "area_ha", "")
del rows
```

Comment: You forgot arcpy.UpdateCursor()

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify the **arcpy** module when calling UpdateCursor.

```
 rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor ("Table2.shp", "", "", "area_eco", "")
```

I second Aaron regarding using the **with** statement

Also, I would reference one of my [OS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599650/how-to-append-all-values-from-a-field-into-an-empty-list-in-python-using-search/24087050#24087050) regarding using either the "classic" cursor or the data access (da) one.

Finally, I would like to point you to a few resources to help you learn python/arcpy:

- [10 Easy way to Tame Python](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/01/12/10-easy-ways-to-tame-python-scripting-in-arcgis/)
- [Seven easy ways to start learning Python](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/03/26/8-easy-ways-learning-python-arcpy/)
- [Esri Blog on Python](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/category/subject-python/)
- [Arcpy Café](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Updating this an trying to run the script, it bounces back with this

`RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Cannot acquire a lock.
Cannot acquire a lock.`

Comment: Close ArcMap/ArcCatalog and other Python IDEs that you have open.

Comment: Weeeell, something happend, but not what I wanted it to do. 
It deleted now my whole attributestable instead of updating it...

Comment: @Stophface I hope you have a backup...

Comment: Sure I do :)
Got it restored already. But where is the problem?!

Comment: Please update your script in your post and I will assist.

Comment: Is there a 'single' row in Table1? If not, then what are the linking fields between Table1 and Table2?  If so, then just use CalculateField to populate the values in Table2. Also, what is the full list of fields to be populated in Table2?

Comment: Table 1 is one row yes, Table 2 has several rows (4 rows) and I want to populate all 4 rows in one field. At the moment the rows in Table 2 are populated with 0. Since I have a huge dataset I want to automate as much as possible and I want to learn more python. Thats why I want to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on here is that the Python interpreter does not know where "UpdateCursor" came from.  The correct syntax is as follows (i.e. ArcGIS 10.1+):

```
arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(YourFeatureclass, ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "etc"])
```

A very clean way to implement a cursor is by using the `with` statement:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(YourFeatureclass, ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "etc"]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
          # Do something
```

Cursor objects are automatically opened, processed in some way and closed automatically using a `with` statement.  More details are available on the ESRI help section on [UpdateCursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000).

Comment: Hey. Thank you! I edited my post. I am not sure how I tell 'do something' to use the value of my search cursor

Comment: @Stophface I would recommend opening a new question to address that.  My initial thought is to run a search cursor and populate a list and then use that list to update a the new table via the update cursor.

Comment: Ah, alright. Well, I tried the script I wrote with the added `arcpy` and it deleted my attributetable the shapefile I wanted to update.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my understanding.  I didn't test the script but this should work. Provide me a link to your data if you need further debugging.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Ecodis_clip_split" 
#set workspace to folder with values

# Create a cursor for Ecodis
cursorEco = arcpy.SearchCursor ("Table1", "", "", "area_ha", "") 
#search for the value in attributetable

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Scoring\\Wetland" 
#set workspace to folder with files which need to be updated

# Create a cursor for Wetland
cursorWet = arcpy.UpdateCursor ("Table2", "", "", "area_ha", "")

# Itereate each row within the Ecodis cursor 
for rowEco in cursorEco:
    print(rowEco.getValue("area_ha"))

    # Itereate each row within the Wetland cursor
    for rowWet in cursorWet:
        # Assign the value of Ecodis row to the Wetland row
        rowWet.setValue("area_ha", rowEco.getValue("area_ha"))
        # Save the changed made to the Weltand
        cursorWet.updateRow(rowWet)

# Clean-up
if cursorEco: 
    del cursorEco
if cursorWet:
    del cursorWet
if rowEco:
    del rowEco
if rowWet:
    del rowWet
```

Comment: Hey
thanks a lot for your effort.
`SyntaxError: Cant assign to function call (<module3>, line 34)`
pops up highlighting this bit of code `rowWet.setValue("area_ha") = rowEco.getValue("area_ha")`
I guess there is a mistake in the Syntax? I put already 4 spaces in there but that did not help.

Comment: @Stophface I've made a change.  See how it works.

Comment: It would likely be more efficient if you accessed the value of row.Eco only once. Also, you can use a try...except block for your deletions. Less lines and it handles exceptions with lock files better.

Comment: `Error executing function. The index passed was not within the valid range`.
Aaaand it delets all my rows in the attributetable where the value is supposed to go in again.

Comment: Hey. I tried something different with a list and had some questions about that. The solution is here
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103515/updatecursor-returns-with-variable-not-defined?noredirect=1#comment145212_103515

Thanks a lot for your effort :)